# BarCodes generator - the best solution

Tags: php, barcode

I need to generate some barcodes for custom discount cards ((with a php class provided by http://www.barcodebakery.com/). An example of a card ID is: `3xxxxxxxxxxY (3 - first digit, x - 10 digits, Y-control digit)`. What is the best barcodes 1D generator method in my case( BUT if those cards will be used in the *near* future for barcode-scanners)?

I`m new with this technology and any help/advice will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a solution very simple using js and css. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7uPJ/1/

```
var div = Barcode(document.getElementById('eTeste').className.match(/barcode\-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/)[1], "code128",{barWidth:2, barHeight:50});
```

Using PHP you may only print the numeric codes. The js will read the numeric codes in classname and will create the bars